# Broadcast video from webcam over NAT

Tags: webcam, ssh

I have two PCs under Windows. First one is behind the corporate NAT with connected USB-webcam and microphone. Another one is in different city and has static public IP.

I need to:

1. Capture video from webcam and sound from micro on 1'st PC (that is behind the NAT)
2. Encrypt and transfer it to 2'nd PC.
3. On 2'nd PC record it in realtime and send data to some virtual webcam and mic to use in other programs like regular webcam (i.e. Skype).

Important condition: traffic must be encrypted.

Think I need something like reverse ssh tunnel and ffmpeg (ffserver).

Interested in a much more lightweight solution, open-source would be better.